# EXCEL - Housekeeping Book

Tags: excel, reference, cell

currently, I am building my housekeeping book in excel and want to use [Open As App](https://www.openasapp.net/home/) to convert the table into an app. My issue is that I have to distinguish between income and expense. There is a list in which you can pick from a dropdown whether it's an income or an expense and add your amount. The amount is one column. I need to set a minus in front of each amount where "expense" was picked before so the balance makes sence. Do you have any ideas how this might be possible? This Open As App thingy has restrictions so i can't make two column for expenxe and income each.

[image: Here I added the - manually]
Here I added the  - manually

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your data

Comment: Have been preparing it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in one of cells say 'D1' or in any empty cell. With this you don't need to add minus sign. This calculation will automatically get updated even if you more values for Income or Expense.

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,"Inc")-SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,"Exp")
```

Comment: Made my day! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Kadepp Please accept/upvote if this has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You need conditional formatting to do this,

[image]

- Select the column
- Select conditional formatting --> new rule
- Select "use formula to determine which cells to format"
- In the formula bar, enter the formula `=A1="exp"`
- Click "format" and select "custom" under category in number tab
- Type your custom format as `-0`

Now you are done. Let me know if you need any help

Answer (score 0):

> so i can't make two column for expenxe and income each

Not sure why this shouldn't work Kadepp.

As for Open as App you could combine a "list" (columns A:C) where you input your data (no formulas needed) with some single result cells showing the sums (G3 and G4) and a final Result in cell G5.

Have you tried s.th. like this:
[double columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ntTk.png)

You can hit me up via the support widget on our website at any time too.

Cheers,
Damian